# jQuery + Rails + Toggle on Image

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, toggle

I have a list of checkboxes with associated images and titles in as labels. I run an `each` loop to pull the data for the checkboxes. I simply want the images to be highlighted when onclick. For some reason, the jQuery toggle script I'm using doesn't work inside the loop.

```
js:

    <script>
      $("img.choice").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("new").toggleClass("new1");
          });
    </script>

css:

    .new {
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888888;

    }

    .new:hover {
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #001f36;
        border-color: #FF804D;
    }

    .new:active {
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #001f36;
        border-color: #FF804D;
    }

    .new1 {
      border: outset;
      border-color: #FF804D;
    }


html:

    <div class="row" align='center'>                    
        <% Category.select { |category| category.gender == 'girl' }.each do |category| %>
            <div class="span4" align="center" style="padding-top:15px">
                <label>
                    <div style="padding-bottom:5px">
                        <h13><%= category.name.capitalize %></h13>
                    </div>
                    <img id="choice-<%= category.id -%>" src= <%= category.image %> class="choice new" />
                    <div>
                        <%= check_box_tag 'category_ids[]', category.id %>
                    </div>
                </label>    
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: `<% Category.where('gender == "girl"').each do |category| %>` might be a better option

Comment: `gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'` - sorry, the element with choice isn't there now, but I tried it on all the `divs`, `imgs`, etc.

Comment: sorry for that foolish error - updated file - Misha, how would I add the `id` to that erb code?

Comment: can you paste the generated html for that div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the reason is that, after iterating through your loop, are having multiple `<img id="choice" />` tags which is invalid HTML. Your `id` is an identifier like you have one as a primary key in your database, it should be unique (at least on that page you're on).

So I would do:

```
<% Category.select { |category| category.gender == 'girl' }.each do |category| %>
  <img id="choice-<%= category.id -%>" src= <%= category.image %> class="choice new" />
<% end %>
```

And the modified JS might look like this:

```
$("img.choice").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("new").toggleClass("new1");
});
```

Remember that this is both untested and straight from my brain.

**edit**
For sake of simplicity, I'd also add a scope to your model, like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :female, where('gender = ?', 'female'), :order => :name # or some other ordering
end
```

So you can do this

```
<% Category.female.each do |category| %>
  [snip]
<% end %>
```

And your logic is a bit split out into your model, where it should belong IMHO.

Comment: hmm, yes, I thought that would the issue as well - but I'm having the same issue having implemented that...thanks though!

Comment: can you please update the code in your question so we can have a look?

Comment: @abhir, you forgot to add a class="choice" to the img tag

Comment: you may need to clean the thing first @Misha M suggested.

Comment: Especially the part of wrapping your code into `$(function(){// code here});`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/misham/xu6Kf/

you need to wrap the JS code in a $(document).ready, so the events get registered:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("img.choice").click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("new").toggleClass("new1");
  });
  }) ;
</script>
```

Ideally, you should place the JS code in the appropriate file in assets:

```
app/assets/javascripts/<controller_name>.js
```

If it doesn't exist, create it.  If it's a CoffeeScript file, you can just rename it to .js, or write in CoffeeScript, if that's your thing.

If you want to keep the code in view file, then put it at the bottom and wrap it in

```
<%= content_for :javascript do -%>
   <!-- JS code here -->
<% end -%>
```

And then place the following right before closing body tag, `</body>`:

```
<%= yield :javascript %>
```

That way your JS code will get automatically rendered at the bottom, not in the middle of the HTML.

Comment: I need the image to be active when clicked - isn't JS the only way to do so?

Comment: fantastic answer. works when I do an individual image - for some reason, its not working within my `each` loop - what a frustrating problem!

Comment: @abhir I've updated the JSFiddle with multiple images.  One item to note, are you adding images through an AJAX call after the page has loaded?  If you are, that event won't get bound to the new images.  You'll have to rerun the `.click` call as part of your `success` callback in AJAX function.

Post some more info and I can try to help